# website hosted outside default website is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I deployed my website as a separate webiste in IIS. It is an intranet website and is windows Authenticated

i followed the below step

created the virtual Path for the published files.
Right click on Sites And select "add website".
gave FSApp as site name. Selceted app pool. gave the virtual path.
in binding left Type and Port unaltered selected the servers ip address in the ip section
gave host name as "fusapp.[domain name.com]"
checked start website immediately.
then Clicked on OK.
Now when i right click on the website and try browse it the site is not opening. It gives the error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

Please let me know what error did i do here

our domain name is like km.com i gave host name like fsapp.km.com will this be an error. On communicating with my colleagues who have already hosted some application in the server they said that they followed similar steps to deploy their app. Also they didn't make any DNS entry as well it seems. I am unsure wether application hosted without DNS entry will work. Please guide me on this as Well

Comment: Did you added new domain to your host file?

Comment: What version of IIS or operating system do you have?  7 is more automatic, but anything before that or running 7 and above in 'classic' mode requires more configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your new domain to your `hosts` file.

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

Add a new line to your host file.

```
    127.0.0.1   fusapp.[domain name.com]
```

Comment: added the url to host file. but now it throws "401.2 unauthorized access when I try to access the site"

Comment: Version details of your IIS?

Comment: i use IIS 7.5 I loginto the server with the my creds km\myuser name. previously when i hosted the App under default website i am able to access the app with my creds. The server's domain name is km-dev. does the difference in the domain name make this issue??

Comment: did you check the domain you have specified in your `web.config` If you add any custom ip+port then you have to update with same in `hosts` file